# hash_hmac in erlang

Tags: erlang

I want to know, is there any way to achieve `hash_hmac("sha256", $token, $signkey, true)` (php) in erlang?

Answer (score 1):

Look at http://erlang.org/doc/apps/crypto/index.html

Comment: Does not seem to support sha256, just SHA-1 (160 digest bits)

Answer (score 1):

I just [googled this](http://steve.vinoski.net/blog/2009/01/02/sha-256-in-erlang/)

Looks like Sha256 is missing from erlang base libraries, but the author on the blog hand coded an implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The [erlsha2](https://github.com/vinoski/erlsha2) library supports sha256 and hmac, as explained in [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942359/hmac-sha256-hex-digest-of-a-string-in-erlang-how).